# Как создать цикл на php что бы тот проводил проверку каждую секунду?

Tags: php

Как создать цикл что бы тот проверял каждую секунду действие?

Условно мне нужно что бы скрипт каждую сайт каждую секунду проверял это:

```
if ( goal() == true) {
echo "goal";
}
```

Как это реализовать без использования cron?

Comment: ```while(1){/*ваш код*/; sleep(1000);};``` сразу говорю - ничего хорошего так не выйдет, но это именно то что вы описали :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков чего вдруг не выйдет?

Comment: @teran Это предположение, основано на том что следующим вопросом будет - как отдать сообщение в браузер :)